# ToC followed by another TOC, how to keep just one?

Tags: table-of-contents, pandoc

I am using **pandoc** and in their default `template.latex`, I want to convert a `.docx` exported from google docs, to a tex PDF with `pdflatex`:

This is `.docx` preview:

[image: docx preview]

You can download: [`sample.docx` wetransfer link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c9ecb55e1aa34f67aae5456c50745bf520191008201640/8c9918124a7fe57a659ca2997d9d44e020191008201640/4b5171)

I convert to `pdf` with `pdflatex` engine:

```
pandoc --output "WIP.pdf" --pdf-engine=pdflatex --from docx --to latex --number-sections --toc --toc-depth=2 -V documentclass=amsart "WIP.docx"
```

It render me a `TOC`, and another thing that look like the a second `TOC` just under.

[image: pdflatex]

This is the `.tex` that I try to convert:

```
\begin{document}
        \maketitle

          {
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \tableofcontents
  }
        \listoftables
          \LR{{\protect\hyperlink{ruxe9flexions-diverses}{Réflexions diverses}
\textbf{1}}}

\begin{quote}
\LR{{\protect\hyperlink{cas-pratique}{Cas pratique} 1}}

\LR{{\protect\hyperlink{je-suis-un-oiseau}{Je suis un oiseau} 1}}

\LR{\protect\hyperlink{je-suis-un-avion}{Je suis un avion} 1}
\end{quote}

\LR{}

\LR{}

\hypertarget{ruxe9flexions-diverses}{%
\section{\texorpdfstring{\LR{Réflexions
diverses}}{Réflexions diverses}}\label{ruxe9flexions-diverses}}

\LR{Ceci est de la réflexion en tout sens.}

\hypertarget{cas-pratique}{%
\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\LR{Cas
pratique}}{Cas pratique}}\label{cas-pratique}}

\LR{Nous avons deux cas pratiques, oiseai et avion.}

\LR{Il est utile de les développer.}

\hypertarget{je-suis-un-oiseau}{%
\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\LR{Je suis un
oiseau}}{Je suis un oiseau}}\label{je-suis-un-oiseau}}

\LR{L'oiseau vol,}

\LR{car il plane avec ses ailes.}

\hypertarget{je-suis-un-avion}{%
\subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\LR{Je suis un
avion}}{Je suis un avion}}\label{je-suis-un-avion}}

\LR{L'avion vol aussi,}

\LR{car il plane avec ses ailes et à un moteur}

        \end{document}
```

If I open the `.docx`, and I remove the `TOC` from the visible document, then I only get the first one.

I want to keep the TOC in `both` Google Doc and LaTeX PDF.

Is there a way to remove that second TOC?

**Edit**

If I downgrade to pandoc `1.17.2`, I have only one toc!

Comment: As you was asked in your other question, please provide something that we can work on. With the information you provide the best that we can do is guess. Also, please read the tooltips of the tags when using them: you tagged _all_ your questions `tex-core`, but none of them were so...

Comment: I have added we transfer link for docx sample, two screenshot, from google doc and after pdf is rendered, also added the tex source file. I have really no clue and I'm blocked for hours on this. No way to remove the second toc, help please?

Comment: Pandoc has no way to know, that some part of your .docx-document is a TOC.

Comment: I use to use xelatex to do the same task and the toc was just rendered once, even if present in the docx. I believe pandoc as a way to know that some part of my docx-document is a TOC, but that's maybe not true when used with pdflatex.

Comment: For example, why do I have `Table des matières Liste des tableaux` at the bottom of the toc and not just `Table des matières` at the top of the TOC? I believe there is something wrong related to that.